# numpy apply function over two 3d matrixes

Tags: python, numpy

So I would like to apply a function over two 3d matrixes with numpy and I can't figure out how. I read about numpy.apply_over_axes() but can't make it work.

This is my code now:

```py
c = np.random.beta(2,3,size=(2,80))

def my_func(a,b):
    xi = np.matmul(b, c)

    spe = np.power(a - xi, 2)
    return spe.sum()

a = np.zeros(shape=(5,1000,80))
b = np.random.beta(2,3,size=(5,1000,2))

np.apply_over_axes(func=my_func,a=[a,b],axes=[0,0,0])
```

Which doesnt work and returns

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1000,80) into shape (5,1000)
```

I will like to iterate though `a` and `b` and apply `my_func` to every vector of the 3rd dimension.

This would do the job but with normal for loops:

```py
results = []
for i in range(len(a)): #5 Iterations
    for j in range(len(a[i])): #1000 Iterations
        results.append(my_func(a[i][j], b[i][j]))
```

I would like to obtain this `results` this but using numpy functions.

Comment: It's good to have a minimal example of the issue, but what are you trying to acheive? What is the expected output?

Comment: I added an expected behavior on the original question, hope it's more clear now. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Thanks; I fixed up your example a bit as it had a few minor syntax issues. This helps, but it's still not completely clear: When you pass in `a[i][j]` as an argument to `my_func`, you end up doing `a[i][j][0][0][0]` which is impossible. Would you be able to fix up your example so it runs?

Comment: sorry, it's updated now and it runs. My_func is basically a placeholder function so I didn't make sure it runned :).

Comment: The example as written now boils down to `results =  a[:,:,0] + b[:,:,0]`. Is that sufficiently general to explain what you need? (I.e., can it be assumed that `my_func` depends only on `a` and `b` through `a[0]` and `b[0]`? If so, I'll add that as an answer; if not, could you provide an example that's closer to what you need?)

Comment: Look at the code of `apolyover`.  It's not doing what you think.  And does not compile your function.

Comment: @fuglede You are correct it could be solved with `a[:,:,0] + b[:,:,0]` but that's because I was using a placeholder function to showcase the example. The function I will apply is indeed a bit more complicated. I just updated the code with a realistic version of my_func(a,b)

Comment: Spelled out an approach to solving that case in the answer below; it's slightly orthogonal to your question because it doesn't use `np.apply_over_axes` at all, but if your `my_func` is indeed representative, then it would also be unnatural to do so.

Comment: The isn't a `numpy` apply that will run your function at compiled speeds.  You have to write the function to work diectly with the 3d arrays.  With some tweaking of the dimensions that shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contraction operation hidden in `np.matmul(b, c)` can be achieved through `np.tensordot(b, c, axes=[2, 0])`, where the `[2, 0]` indicates that the third axis in `b` is contracted with the first axis in `c`. That is, `np.tensordot(b, c, axes=[2, 0]).shape` is `(5, 1000, 80)`. From there on, ordinary broadcasting applies, and your code boils down to

```py
a = np.zeros(shape=(5, 1000, 80))
b = np.random.beta(2, 3, size=(5, 1000, 2))
c = np.random.beta(2, 3, size=(2, 80))

xi = np.tensordot(b, c, axes=[2, 0])
spe = np.power(a - xi, 2)
results2 = spe.sum(axis=2)
```

Let's check that this indeed matches what you get by simply using loops:

```py
In [55]: results = np.array(results).reshape(5, 1000)

In [56]: np.allclose(results, results2)
Out[56]: True
```

Answer (score -1):

Running your code in an `ipython` session:

```
In [88]: c = np.random.beta(2,3,size=(2,80)) 
    ...:  
    ...: def my_func(a,b): 
    ...:     xi = np.matmul(b, c) 
    ...:  
    ...:     spe = np.power(a - xi, 2) 
    ...:     return spe.sum() 
    ...:  
    ...: a = np.zeros(shape=(5,1000,80)) 
    ...: b = np.random.beta(2,3,size=(5,1000,2)) 
    ...:  
    ...: np.apply_over_axes(func=my_func,a=[a,b],axes=[0,0,0])                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-c5e5a66c9d0a> in <module>
     10 b = np.random.beta(2,3,size=(5,1000,2))
     11 
---> 12 np.apply_over_axes(func=my_func,a=[a,b],axes=[0,0,0])

<__array_function__ internals> in apply_over_axes(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py in apply_over_axes(func, a, axes)
    485 
    486     """
--> 487     val = asarray(a)
    488     N = a.ndim
    489     if array(axes).ndim == 0:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     83 
     84     """
---> 85     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     86 
     87 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1000,80) into shape (5,1000)
```

You should have shown us the full error with traceback.

That traceback shows us that it is trying make one array from your list of two.  Since the shapes don't match, it raises an error.  With a different mismatch it would have created a (2,) object array, which would just move raise problems later:

```
In [89]: np.array([a,b])                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-964832cdcfcd> in <module>
----> 1 np.array([a,b])

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (5,1000,80) into shape (5,1000)
```

But the problem is you did not read the docs, or take them seriously:

```
func : function
    This function must take two arguments, `func(a, axis)`.
a : array_like
    Input array.
axes : array_like
    Axes over which `func` is applied; the elements must be integers.
```

`a` is supposed to be an array, not a list of two arrays.  `func` is supposed to take an `axis` parameter, not another array.  And I don't know what you are trying to do with `[0,0,0]`.  For 3d arrays `[0,1]` might apply, but not a repeated 0.

### your loop

With a bit better `numpy` style:

```
In [91]: results = [] 
    ...: for i in range(a.shape[0]): #5 Iterations 
    ...:     for j in range(a.shape[1]): #1000 Iterations 
    ...:         results.append(my_func(a[i,j], b[i,j])) 
    ...:                                                                        
In [92]: np.array(results).shape                                                
Out[92]: (5000,)
```

### rework my_func

To do this without the loops, we need to use whole-array functions within `my_func`.  There isn't a `numpy` `apply` that compiles python code - you have to look at `numba` or `cython` for that.

`xi=np.matmul(b,c)`.  `b` is (5,1000,2), `c` is (2,80).  `matmul` is happy doing a `dot` combining the last axis of `b` with the 2nd to the last of `c`.

```
In [93]: xi = np.matmul(b,c)                                                    
In [94]: xi.shape                                                               
Out[94]: (5, 1000, 80)
```

That matches `a`, so

```
In [97]: spe = np.power(a-xi,2)                                                 
In [98]: spe.shape                                                              
Out[98]: (5, 1000, 80)
```

then sum on that last axis:

```
In [99]: res = spe.sum(axis=2)                                                  
In [100]: res.shape                                                             
Out[100]: (5, 1000)
```

which matches your loop:

```
In [101]: np.allclose(res.ravel(), np.array(results))                           
Out[101]: True
```

Except for the last `sum`, your `myfunc` runs with the whole arrays.

```
In [103]: my_func(a,b)                                                          
Out[103]: 46883.49325596101
```